# .NET MAUI App Does Not Create Pdb Symbol Files For Project References When Deploying To Emulator - Cannot Debug Referenced Projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

I have a .net MAUI Application that I render out to Android and iOS. When I'm developing and debugging over Android Emulator I can debug ALL of the code in the MAUI Project. BUT I also have reference to other projects we have written (Class Libraries and such) that have DataModels, Clients etc. that are unable to be debugged.

Ex. Create Account screen uses a model from a Project Reference that has Validation Methods and such. I am completely unable to "step into" the code for that project to debug the model's validity. This is just one example. I also cannot step into my "Clients (HTTP CLients) project that calls the API and so on.

When looking at the "Modules" panel during debugging I see the Referenced DLLs in the list BUT under the Symbol Status column, it states "Symbols not loaded" and no pdb file is referenced in the "Symbol File" column.

I DO see the pdb files loaded for the MAUI Project, but that's the only one that loads, even though I reference multiple other projects in the solution for API Clients, Models, etc.

How can I get MAUI to create the pdb symbol files on the device for the referenced projects so I can debug those as well? I have looked at many different forums and different setting configurations, but nothing will output the symbol files,

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2022 and output is .net7.

Thanks

Billy

Comment: I created a new maui project and maui class library. I added the reference of the library  in my project and added a breakpoint in the library. When I debug the project the breakpoint will be hit.

Comment: still not working on my side. When I try to hit the breakpoint in the other library, it makes the app pause showing a threading issue. All of the project references are from the same solution and I've got the symbols loaded.